# Execute a python script from an html buton

Tags: python, html, flask, server

I'm trying to run my python script from an html form.
I've tried using Flask but I must be making a mistake somewhere because when I run python ./main.py I manage to execute my script and when I have my web page on a separate server and send the form nothing happens.
But I also don't understand how, without executing a python ./main.py command, my script can be executed.
If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd love to hear from you.

tag redirecting to my main.html:

```
<li class=""><a title="Ajouter un flux"
    href="{{ asset('kelklopeFlux/templates/main.html') }}">Ajouter un flux</a> </li>
```

main.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'
app.template_folder = 'templates'


@app.route('/uploadFile', methods=['POST'])
def uploadFile():
         // Rest of my code \\
        return render_template('index.html', found_items=found_items, not_found_items=not_found_items, found_itemLength=found_itemLength, not_found_itemsLength=not_found_itemsLength)


@app.route('/uploadLink', methods=['POST'])
def uploadLink():
    // Rest of my code \\
    return render_template('index.html', found_items=found_items, not_found_items=not_found_items, found_itemLength=found_itemLength, not_found_itemsLength=not_found_itemsLength)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    messages = get_flashed_messages()
    return render_template('main.html', messages=messages)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

main.html:

```
<form action="../uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Choose a file:</label>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <form action="../uploadLink" method="post">
      <label for="url">Enter a URL:</label>
      <input type="url" id="url" name="url" required />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: When you run this code locally, does it work but not on the server? 
Have you read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/ ?

Comment: @mx0 when I run it locally on my terminal it works well. And yes I'm trying to understand what's to goal of using Waitress ( for example ) and how can it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `/uploadFile` instead of `../uploadFile`. The directory does not matter because it is a flask route, not a directory. Same thing goes for the second form.